# How to set a legend which is prodcted in lineplot as the rowlabe of table

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I have a series, and use `ax.plot` creat a line plot.Then I use `ax.table` add a table below the line plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [4.6, 4.8, 4.7, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]
index = ['3m','6m', '1year', '2year', '3year', '5year', '10year']
s = pd.Series(data,index=index)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(1, 8)
pic = ax.plot(x, s)
plt.xticks([])
leg = plt.legend('rate')
row_lables = ['xxx']
table = ax.table(cellText=[data], colLabels=index, rowLoc='center',colLoc='center',cellLoc='center', rowLabels = row_lables)
plt.show()
```

[raw_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soV4V.png)

I would like to set the legend as the rowlabe of table (the legend replaces the string 'legend'). How can i create this picture.
[image: result_plot]

Comment: Just to make sure: Instead of the letter `r` in the legend you want to have the complete table? (Which is longer than the plot, so the legend would overlap the axes?) In any case it would be useful to provide the code you use, see [mcve].

Comment: Thx, my english is poor.I want to replace 'xxx' in picture by the legend.Thank you for your help.

Comment: This will be hard. It's definitively non-standard and would require some hacking into the internals of the table and legend.